# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given. on Raw Sql

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I implemented a method which uses `DB::raw` and `DB::select`. The query is fine, but my result is `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

I've used the `DB::raw` and `DB::select` in the past with no issues. Not sure why this is occurring.

```
public function maps(Request $request){
    $lat = $request->input('lat');
    $lon = $request->input('lng');
    $radius = $request->input('radius');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM listings WHERE lat<>'.$lat.' and `long`<>'.$lon.' and (3958*3.1415926*sqrt((
    lat-'.$lat.')*(lat-'.$lat.') + cos(lat/57.29578)*cos('.$lat.'/57.29578)*(`long`-'.$lon.')*(`long`-'.$lon.'))/180) <= '.$radius;
    $mapsData=DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
    return $mapsData;
}
```

Comment: The result of the query might be `false`, and just beware of the SQL Injection vulnerability here

Comment: the query produces results in my database lookup

Comment: I just tried `return \DB::select(\DB::raw('select * from users'));` locally and it works fine ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Saly3301 how do i solve the sql injection vulnerability here?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#running-queries  parameter bindings